# GridView.PageIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

I thought  GridView.PageIndexChanged event signals that ObjectDataSource retrieved rows for appropriate page, but I’m probably wrong, since this event happens before ObjectDataSource control rebinds to data source. What this event signals then? Only that GridView now knows what values will parameters maximumRows  and startRowIndex have?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

This event signals that someone clicked on something (typically your pager control) that changed the visible page of your GridView, so yeah, it pretty much means that you now know where to start your new page of data.

Technically, I don't think you know what startRowIndex is since that's calculated from pageSize and pageIndex, but that's really just semantics.